# Azure Communication Service chat not working in azure app

Tags: chat, azure-communication-services

I am trying to implement chat functionality using azure communication services. It works 90% fine on local, but after deploying it is not working.

There is a code block in the sample to list the participant count that should be 2, for a successful communication but it returns only 1. Don't know why the abnormal behavior is been shown.

Comment: Hi, can you please share the link to the sample you're referring to?
Also, it'd be very great if you could share: 1) exact steps to reproduce the problem, 2) any potential errors you get along the way (you say it works 90% on local - what happens in the remaining 10%?), 3) any customizations to the sample code.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/chat/get-started?pivots=programming-language-javascript

Comment: steps are just to initiate the chat....it gives only single participant in chat

Comment: can you provide me something, if you have came across, to build a two way chat communication using signalR and azure communication services

Answer (score 0):

> It works 90% fine on local, but after deploying it is not working.

I just grabbed the [finalized code from GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-javascript-quickstarts/tree/main/add-chat) and deployed it to Netlify and it works flawlessly.

> There is a code block in the sample to list the participant count that should be 2, for a successful communication but it returns only 1.

There are actually two code blocks listing the participants:

1. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-javascript-quickstarts/blob/c5090668cfe3adea6d3fb2b1f154a842f970efc4/add-chat/client.js#L84
2. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-javascript-quickstarts/blob/c5090668cfe3adea6d3fb2b1f154a842f970efc4/add-chat/client.js#L91

The second one lists the participants after one of them is removed. Please make sure you're looking at the right console output.

Also, if you've modified the code and possibly running multiple instances of the app, make sure you're on the right chat thread.

> can you provide me something, if you have came across, to build a two way chat communication using signalR and azure communication services

Yeah, I build a sample app utilizing Blazor, SignalR, and Azure Communication Services. So far, it contains just chat. Check the sources at: https://github.com/petrsvihlik/AcsBlazor